# Am I using MoveNext correctly?

Tags: c#

I've written a small code snippet to create 3D model objects. The object takes two points to use as insertion points (start an end). The Problem is *two* objects are being created using the exact same start and end points. I assume it's a elementary problem with the way I'm using MoveNext... Sorry there's not much context to work with, does anything obvious jump out at you with the way I'm using MoveNext? Thank you

```
PointList2.RemoveAt( 0 ) ; var pointenumstart = PointList.GetEnumerator();
var pointenumend = PointList2.GetEnumerator();
TSG.Point start = PointList[0];
TSG.Point end = PointList2[0]; 
for (int i  =  0 ;  i <=TotalPickedColumns ; i ++ ) 
{
Beam Panel = new Beam(Beam.BeamTypeEnum.PANEL);
DadoPanel panel = new DadoPanel(Panel, start, end);
panel.PanelHeight =  textBox_PanelHeight.Text ; panel.PanelThickness =  textBox_PanelThickness.Text ; panel.PanelDepth =  textBox_PanelDepth.Text ; double t = 0;
BeamList[0] .GetReportProperty( "PROFILE.HEIGHT", ref t);
panel.PositionPlaneOffset =  t* 0.5 ; 

if (pointenumend.MoveNext() &&pointenumstart.MoveNext() ) 
{
start =  pointenumstart.Current ; end =  pointenumend.Current ;  
}
panel.CreateDadoPanel() ;
```

Comment: Have you seen the LINQ `Zip` operator?

Comment: Are you using `GetEnumerator()` because the two collections (`PointList` and `PointList`) may have a different number of Items? If so, you need to make a decision when the `if` condition is not met. If they do, you don't need `GetEnumerator()`. Anyway, the two `MoveNext()` should be called before you use the values, otherwise the first two `start` / `end` will be the same. You can then remove the two `TSG.Point` assignments (outside the loop).

Comment: If it is not working your logic is wrong.  Take out a piece of paper and test your code to find error.  I find it is easier to fix issues like this off line.  Sometimes I create a log file and put debug info into the log.  Then print out log file to find issues.

Comment: @Jimi, the two collections always have different number of items. PointList2 is a duplicate of PointList (startPoint) with the first Point removed in order for it to always one Point ahead ( hence endPoint). Moving the the while loop to be called first moves the problem i.e. the 4th 3D object is being duplicated, not the first anymore.

Comment: Read again my previous comment *If so, you need to make a decision when the if condition is not met*. You, apparently, just keep going.